# pure virtual final functions : legal in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, final, pure-virtual

```
class Foo
{
public: 
    virtual int foo() final = 0;
};
```

Compiles fine.

Isn't `Foo` just a waste of space, and an accident in the making? Or am I missing something?

Comment: imho yep, in this case Foo is a whaste of space.

Comment: Well, you have an abstract class that you cannot instantiate, but you can also never derive a concrete class from it... congratulations?

Comment: I meant for `dynamic_cast` you need a vptr and `foo()` ensures that.

Comment: @ipc dynamic cast between what and what?

Comment: Its a paradox like *this sentence is a lie*

Comment: @ipc you need an object to use `dynamic_cast`. You can't create an object because the class is abstract. So I ask again - dynamic cast between what and what?

Comment: @ipc: `dynamic_cast` requires an object, and neither this class nor any class derived from it can be instantiated.

Comment: Why would it be a waste of space if you can't instantiate it?

Comment: @onemasse: A waste of space in the source file, since you can't do anything sensible with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is **almost** a complete waste of space, as you've said. There is at least one admittedly contrieved usage for this. The fact that it compiles, by the way, is not surprising. As long as code is legitimate, it needs not "make sense" to compile.

Say you want to use `Foo` as a policy. That means it will be used as a template parameter, but it needs not be instantiated. In fact, you really *don't want* anyone to ever instantiate the class (although admittedly I wouldn't know why, what can it hurt).

This is exactly what you have here. A class with a type that you can lay your hands on, but you can't instantiate it (though making the constructor private would probably be a lot more straightforward).

As an added bonus, you could add `enum`s or static functions inside the class scope. Those could be used without actually instantiating, and they'd be within that class' namespace.  So, you have a class that's primarily usable only as type, but you still have "some functionality" bundled with it in the form of static functions.

Most of the time, one would probably just wrap that stuff into a namespace, but who knows, in some situation, this might be the desired way.

Comment: Although, even if you do want to prevent instantiation, this is rather a quirky way to do it. Deleting the constructor would express the intent rather more clearly.

Answer (score 10):

> Isn't Foo just a waste of space

Indeed it is; you can't instantiate it since it's abstract, and you can't override the function to make a non-abstract derived class.

It could be used as a way of preventing a class from being instantiated, if you want to do that for some reason; but even then it would probably make more sense to delete the default constructor.

> and an accident in the making?

Not really. Since you can't do anything with the class, you can't do anything wrong with it.

Comment: I thought I might run into trouble with pointer and '->', but forgot that no object of this class can ever be created.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm reading the grammar in 9.2 correctly this is actually legal although I may have missed something in the notes prohibiting it.

> member-declarator:
>   declarator virt-specifier-seq(opt) pure-specifier(opt)

Then it shows that `virt-specifier-seq` can be `final` and `pure-specifier` is `= 0`

I can't see any way this would be useful although there may be some corner case that makes use of it.